# Counting hidden classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, v8

How to count the total number of hidden classes generated in JavaScript program using v8 compiler? or the memory used for all the generated hidden classes using v8 compiler? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the number of unique hidden classes?

As far as I understand 'hidden classes' in V8 sources are known as 'maps'. Each heap object in V8 has a pointer to a map (or bit-encoded map id) which takes up 1 word of memory (See `v8/src/objects.h`, grep for Map, map_word).

Probably the most helpful for you is the v8's `--trace_maps` option. Then if v8 with this option does not give you enough information you can see where in the source it is produced and instrument it to your liking.

(Disclamer: I am **not** on the V8 team, so I might err. I've been hacking on v8 for quite some time though).